# Ошибка при разворачивание окна из трея Win 10

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-10

При разворачивании приложения из трея вылетает ошибка `Cannot remove shell notification icon`. Заметил что вылетает ошибка тогда когда оно одно в трее. Если же например в трее еще приложение(например диспетчер задач), то все нормально. Вот код даблклика на иконку. Обрамил `try except`  для получения сообщение. иначе вылетает без предупреждений.

```
procedure TForm1.TrayIcon1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    TrayIcon1.Visible := False;
    Show();
    WindowState := wsNormal;
    Application.BringToFront();
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Это не ответ, просто похожая проблема была. Может натолкнет на мысль, куда копать.

Версия D какая?
У меня тоже с треем проблема (D 10.3) - перестали отображаться всплывающие hint из компонента TrayIcon. [тут была](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1124119/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-windows-10-%D0%B8-delphi-10-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82?noredirect=1#comment1942679_1124119)
Хотя компиляция на старой версии 10.1 при запуске показывает все верно.
Если вы участник D Embarcadero online и покупали, то задайте вопрос в ТП. Хотя о чем я? :)

Я попробовал много вариантов, ничего не работает.
Подозреваю, что и Em и Ms под Win 10 усиленно пилят Api и у них нестыковки.
Новую версию D пока ставить не хочу, но думаю там заработает. + BugFix будет негласный.

Код у вас верный, но я все же бы попробовал сначала показать окно (и ранее проблемы были и с фронт и стейт), а потом с треем игрался. Наверное пробовали? И местами менять.
+в настройках формы (виз), надеюсь, эти параметры дефолтные и меняются, когда форма в трей скрывается?

++А версия W10 какая? Есть конечно, вероятность, что в трее какое-то приложение не стандартное висит, но маленькая. Если у вас правильная винда и ПК - совет - разверните на ней виртуалку (Hyper-V\VmWare) с отличной от вашей версией Win (оптимально Win 10 Ent Ltsc последнюю) и проверьте тем работу своей проги (вообще если ПО пишете - рекомендуется как бы на разных версиях проверять), можете еще Win7 поставить как вариант и там смотреть. Перед проверкой не забудьте обновить винду через WU.

+теперь гугл\Ян на "delphi Cannot remove shell notification" может новое чего покажет?